# Combinations Question?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many ways can 6 different books be distributed between 2 students, provided that both students receive at least one book?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Related :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158130/permuting-15-books-about-2-shelves-with-at-least-one-book-on-each-shelf

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We assume the books are all different. It is easier to count the number of ways to divide without restriction, and then subtract the $2$ forbidden ways.

Call the students $A$ and $B$. The number of ways to distribute *without restriction* is the number of ways to select a **subset** of the books to give to $A$. (So $B$ gets the rest.) How many subsets of the set of books are there?

Comment: I'm unsure, but would the total number of arrangements be 6C2?

Comment: I can't resist making a joke. The right answer is obtained by removing the $C$ (it is $62$, that is, $2^6-2$ (a set of $n$ objects has $2^n$ subsets).

Comment: Wait, where can I learn more about these subsets?

Comment: You will gradually as you go through the course. But to see there are $2^6$ ways to distribute the books, imagine you line them up alphabetically, and put an A sticker on the ones you will give to A, and a B sticker on the ones you will give to B. There are as many ways to distribute the books as there are "words" of length $6$ made up of the letters A and or B. And there are $2^6$ such words, since we have $2$ choices for the first letter, and for each such choice $2$ choices for the second letter, and for each choice of first and second, we have $2$ choices for the third letter, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

**First Method**: Give the first boy $m$ books and the rest to the second boy. This can be one in $\binom{6}{m}$ ways, $m=1,\cdots,5$
$$\sum_{m=1}^5\binom{6}{m}=2^6-2$$

**Alternative**: This can also be solved as, there are $6$ blank spaces corresponding to the $6$ books and they have to be filled by $2$ symbols corresponding to the $2$ boys. This can be done in $2^6$ ways,and we have to exclude the $2$ cases where each of the $6$ blanks are filled with one symbol only.